# How can I persist user's logging in more than 1 hour in firebase in react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I tried to persist user's logging in from after user logged in to before user logged out but 1 hour after logging in user using Firebase, problem that `firebase.auth().currentUser` became `null` occurred. in this situation How do I keep the user logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I keep the user logged in?

As explained in the documentation on [Authentication State Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence), with the JS SDK, by default **a signed in user is indefinitely persisted until explicit sign out**. So normally you should not do anything to have this persistence.

Concretely, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#the_user_lifecycle), when the access token expires after one hour, the SDK uses the refresh token behind the scene to get a new valid set of tokens.

*If you have a specific reason to manage this persistence yourself instead of taking advantage of the standard mechanism, please update your question accordingly.*

Comment: thanks for answer. I don't know about standard mechanism. so I wrote this. but now I see the other document to get to know. thanks